# Change .dbshell location?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB cli client stores history in ~/.dbshell, is it possible to disable it or change its location? Something similar to MYSQL_HISTFILE.

I've took a look at [this document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/), but it seems like impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the .dbshell history file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993736/how-can-i-change-the-dbshell-history-file-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it's not possible atm. The name is hardcoded in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/deb9f8e6bf9517061404cf2f476cd08f60687d83/src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp#L112 :

```
boost::filesystem::path mongo::shell_utils::getHistoryFilePath() {
    static const auto& historyFile = *new boost::filesystem::path(getUserDir() / ".dbshell");

    return historyFile;
}
```

Comment: There’s an incredibly dirty workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65994967/1968